# Send multiple media files from Twilio using nodejs

Tags: node.js, twilio-api

I tried to send MMS using Twilio node API with multiple image URL but it is sending only last image file.

`client.messages.create({
        body: body,
        to: TO,
        from: FROM,
        mediaUrl: [
          'https://example.com/first.png',
          'https://example.com/second.png',
        ],
      }, (err, mes) => {
        console.log(err)
      });`


And I received this message with all white spaces removed from string and all characters are joined when attached image URL.

Anybody know how to get through this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of sending multiple images you can add nested images and do it in one go.

Also, the white spaces are not visible only if you are using any external app for receiving messages. Normally the white spaces are visible in most of the mobiles.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try that.

Comment: @Jack Can you please show code as to what you mean by `nested`?

Comment: This answer has a low quality without a code showing the proposed solution